# Default all backbone model new url to .json and models to include ID

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using the standard Rails stack with Backbone. Following the tutorial here: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/ I got the following code:

```
Models.Users = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    var base = '/users'
    if (this.isNew()) return base + '.json';
    else return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
  }
});
```

This code works great.

However, whenever I create a new model, I am copying and pasting the exact same two lines of code:

```
    if (this.isNew()) return base + '.json';
    else return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
```

The only thing I change in the code is the base variable.

That seems very wrong. Is there a way to to do this better? Am I not suppose to modify Backbone's url like this to make it work with Rails? Is there a better way so I do not have to copy and paste the same line of code over and over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, whenever I create a new model, I am copying and pasting the exact same two lines of code

What do you mean? Why do you need to do that if you are instantiating the same model? However it's not clear if you mean creating new (separate) models. If you are doing that you could just throw this code in a Models base-class so to speak:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 url: function(base){
  if(base)
   //... do something

  else
   //... do something else
 }
```

You can then directly inherit other models from MyModel:

```
var AnotherModel = MyModel.extend({...});
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly, something like this should solve your problem. Just check for the existence of base so that when Backbone queries for `url()` without a parameter it can still return a valid value. You could initialize these `base`es by passing it as an option to `initialize` method of the model.

If it's not inheritance, then just create method similar to the `url` one above and just pass in the `parameter` for every model.

I'm not really sure what the confusion is but IMHO both of these should work :)

Comment: Yes, by creating new models I meant creating new separate models.
The base class solution works very well.